# How to search Feeds?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, open-source, rss, feed

I want to create an iPhone project which search feeds, like in google reader if we search for some word in "Add a subsciption" tab it will display all feeds related to that so we can add feeds easily. Any Idea how it can be done.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I am stuck while creating search engine... Like if we give some keyword in search field of our app it should disply all feeds(rss,atom,xml any) related to keyword so user can easily subscribe those feeds easily without entering feed url.

Comment: Someone somewhere needs to provide a list of known feeds. You can't literally "search the Internet" from a single iPhone ... The best resource is the one that already indexes the BILLIONS of pages out there. Your iPhone, no matter how well programmed, is a bit underpowered to do so in any reasonable length of time. Use Google.

Comment: Just as a followup (because I think this is the conceptual problem you're having), you might want to read this informative article: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/search-engine.htm - it's important to note that search engines basically build lists. They don't do a live scan of all possible web sites to look for your search term.

Comment: But i saw some iPhone apps where they provide option to search feeds. Do they maintain there own servers...

Comment: I found this...http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#findFeeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#findFeeds
And it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Google Reader, presumably, relies on Google's own vast collection of known feeds and its search engine to locate relevant ones. My guess is you'd probably need to do the same (maybe use their [FeedBurner API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/feedburner/)) unless you plan to create and maintain a service to collect, categorize, and offer up feeds to searches.

Comment: ...of course you could just be asking how to interface with such a service in an iOS app, but that's a VERY vague question without at least naming a service you intend to use.

Comment: Is there is any other way to search feeds without using google account, like if we give "apple" in the search field it should display feeds related to "apple".